# Установка vqmod на Opencart

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Собственно сам вопрос - если на сайте уже установлен vqmod, то будет ли ошибка при попытке повторной установки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторная установка просто выведет сообщение, что он уже установлен
vqmod has been installed successfully.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?